# How to get label of the node in lightning-tree in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, lightningtreegrid

What is the way to get the ***label*** of the lightning-tree node on-click/on-select on javascript handler in lwc?

**myLwc.html** :

```
<lightning-tree items={sidebarStructure} onselect={handleSidebar}></lightning-tree>
```

**myLwc.js** :

```
sidebarStructure= [
             {
                label: 'Europe Sales Manager',
                name: '13',
                expanded: false,
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Sales Rep1',
                        name: '14',
                        expanded: true,
                        items: [],
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Sales Rep2',
                        name: '15',
                        expanded: true,
                        items: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
];


handleSidebar(event){
    console.log('****Sidebar1::'+event.target.label); // giving undefined as result
    console.log('****Sidebar2::'+event.currentTarget.label); // giving undefined as result
    console.log('****Sidebar3::'+event.detail.label); // giving undefined as result
    console.log('****Sidebar4::'+event.currentTarget.items); //giving full tree's JSON as result
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get the `name`. It's up to you to find the appropriate element. The documentation recommends having a mapping object, though you could also do this on the fly.

```
  handleSelect(event) {
    const findNode = (nodeList, name) =>
      nodeList.find((node) => node.name === name) ||
      nodeList.reduce(
        (p, v) => p || (v.items && findNode(v.items, name)),
        null
      );
    this.selectedLabel = findNode(this.items, event.detail.name).label;
  }
```

Included is a [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/e5vuV7Mtc/1/edit) demo.

Comment: it solved the problem !! I somehow missed the documented part of mapping and that costs me several hours.

Comment: HI @sfdcfox, do you know the equivalent of this function for lightning-tree-grid? (or if it is possible to do so on lightning-tree-grid?). I tried this on 'onrowselection', but it did not work. Thank you.

Comment: @user2018 It's the same algorithm, but use `_children` instead of `items`, or you can use a mapping object.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid it does not work for me. `event.detail.name` always return `undefined`. `event.detail` returns an array of currently selected row. It is on 'rowselection' event.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree/documentation) what you can do is:

```
mapping = {
    '13': 'Europe Sales Manager',
    '14': 'Sales Rep1',
    '15': 'Sales Rep2'
};

sidebarStructure = theStructure;
    handleSidebar(event){
        console.log('Label is: ' + mapping[event.detail.name]);
}
```

You can find a link to a working Salesforce LWC Playground [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/oaXubRMdZ/2/edit).

Comment: yes that's what I was missing, thanks for the response!!